# players.getScopedPlayerIds error 400 Calling application is not linked

Tags: oauth-2.0

Problems encountered in obtaining PGS new player ID.
The server accesses `getScopedPlayerIds` through `serverAuthCode` through lib `com.google.api.services.games.Games`.

> GET https://games.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me/scopedIds

get an incorrect result

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Calling application is not linked to a developer account or linked to multiple accounts through different Android games.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Calling application is not linked to a developer account or linked to multiple accounts through different Android games."
}
```

Other information:
The `/games/v1/players/{playerId}` interface can be successfully accessed using the same `serverCode`.
With the interfaces under other players, only the `v1/players/me/scopedIds` interface reports an error.

The error message says that Calling application is not linked to a developer account or linked to multiple accounts through different Android games.
I suspect it has something to do with the developer console or  cloud console.